# Is there an easy way to style KML files on a graduated colour scale based on field values when uploading to a Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, kml, web-mapping, google-maps-api, google

I am creating a Google Map which includes one polygon layer of census output areas and one point layer. Because the polygon layer is so large and there are limitations on the number and size of layers you can upload to a Google Map (10 layers max of no more than 2000 features and max 5MB), I am having to split the data into twenty individual KML files and create two separate maps with 10 files each. When I add the KML files to my Google Map, I would like to easily be able to categorise the polygons into a graduated colour scheme, with red for low values and green for high values. However there is no option to do this easily (like in QGIS or ArcGIS) as in screenshot below. The `range` option is not available for some reason, even though the columns I want to use are in number format. Is there some kind of workaround or am I doing something wrong?
[image]